# How to get matched aggregations based on SWICHID calculate the avarage time in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I am working on sample application in react in that I am using aggregations, I implemented a query matching **SWITCHID** field and **STATUS** to get all data where **status** is **LIGHTS ON** .How to get the difference between average time based on RECEIVEDDATE and CREATE_DATE fields.

db.lights.aggregate([   {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}},   {"$sort":{"RECEIVEDDATE":1,"CREATE_DATE":1}},   {"$group":{     "_id":"$SWITCHID",     "LIGHTONALLTIME":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}   }},{$out:"bhavana"} ])

```
my fields:
            "_id" : "Z5-W52-53A/8.",
            "LIGHTONALLTIME" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2eb"),
                    "SWITCHID" : "Z5-W52-53A/8.",
                    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 260.79,
                    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
                    "LATITUDE" : 17.6755,
                    "LONGITUDE" : 83.1965,
                    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2010-01-10-13.44.16.719000",
                    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-96",
                    "FLAG2" : "K",
                    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-03.04.03.621000"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2e6"),
                    "SWITCHID" : "Z5-W52-53A/8.",
                    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 260.79,
                    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
                    "LATITUDE" : 17.6755,
                    "LONGITUDE" : 83.1965,
                    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-01-10-13.44.16.719000",
                    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-96",
                    "FLAG2" : "K",
                    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-00.04.06.952000"
                },
        "_id" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
            "LIGHTONALLTIME" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2be"),
                    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
                    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 257.39,
                    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
                    "LATITUDE" : 17.7429,
                    "LONGITUDE" : 83.2542,
                    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-00.12.17.494000",
                    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-84",
                    "FLAG2" : "K",
                    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-00.04.06.952000"
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8bab026c44f9d64085a2c6"),
                    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
                    "TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,
                    "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 257.7,
                    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
                    "LATITUDE" : 17.7429,
                    "LONGITUDE" : 83.2542,
                    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-04.25.35.232000",
                    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-84",
                    "FLAG2" : "K",
                    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-04.04.05.591000"
                },`enter code here`
```

Comment: can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue...

Comment: suggest me how to solve this issue...Veeamsir@Veeram

Comment: can you give clarity on **How to get the difference between average time based on RECEIVEDDATE and CREATE_DATE fields**, an example maybe

Comment: time difference CREATE_DATE to  RECEIVEDDATE  

ex :RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-04.25.35.232000"
     CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-04.04.05.591000 
     diffrence:21 min somthing ....@Akhilesh Krishnan

Comment: Finding difference in two timestamp  CREATE_DATEtimestamp  and  RECEIVEDDATEtimestamp @Akhilesh krishnan

Comment: no average finding an all right ?

Comment: no all , each switchId 
related output:
[ {SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4, duration: 7}, {SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5, duration: 5}]  @  Akhilesh krishnan  sir

Comment: forexample: 
[{SWITCHID" : "Z5-W52-53A/8, CREATE_DATE to RECEIVEDDATE DURATION:30},
{SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4, CREATE_DATE to RECEIVEDDATE DURATION:24}]

this is my expected output


]@  Akhilesh krishnan sir any idea

Comment: Try  `duration: {$push:{$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}}` in group stage

Comment: @NareshG if your still not able to figure i have one more question to help you out so there are multipe **receivedDate** and **createdDate** for a given **switchId** so how should we handle that case (ie.we have two sets of receivedDate and createdDate for one switchId), but the output shows only one aggregated duration value so what is the approach ?

Comment: i try this code:
db.lights.aggregate([ {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}},  {$project: {       duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$CREATE_DATE", "$RECEIVEDDATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} ])
 display like error message:errmsg" : "cant $subtract astring from a string", @Veeram sir

Comment: @Veeram  sir i try this code
db.lights.aggregate([  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}}, {$project: {       duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} ])

My output is:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964e73f6f90ba43dfb1956"), "duration" : 0.10095944444444445 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964ea2f6f90ba43dfb1957"), "duration" : 24.004166666666666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964eb6f6f90ba43dfb1958"), "duration" : 0.004166666666666667 }
 how to get the all fields in each id

Comment: @ Akhilesh krishnan sir yes your wright 
first i try this each objectId duration ofter i write the aggregation based on switchId  average duration calculate I try this code
db.lights.aggregate([  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}}, {$project: {       duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}  }} ])
out put:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964e73f6f90ba43dfb1956"), "duration" : 0.10095944444444445 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964ea2f6f90ba43dfb1957"), "duration" : 24.004166666666666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a964eb6f6f90ba43dfb1958"), "duration" : 0.004166666666666667 }

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the post ?

Comment: @Veeram sir   My expected output is:
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5a964e73f6f90ba43dfb1956"),   "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4","TOTALSTREETLIGHTS" : 22,"WORKINGSTREETLIGHTS" : 22, "CUMULATIVEKWH" : 257.7,
   "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON", "LATITUDE" : 17.7429,
                    "LONGITUDE" : 83.2542,
                    "RECEIVEDDATE" : "2018-02-09-04.25.35.232000",
                    "OFFICE_ID" : "200-84",
                    "FLAG2" : "K",
                    "CREATE_DATE" : "2018-02-09-04.04.05.591000"
                     "duration" : 24.004166666666666 }

Comment: as well as each object same output

Comment: Use $addFields instead of $project in your aggregation. Something like  `$addfields: {duration:{$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}}`

Comment: @Veeram i try this code 
db.lights.aggregate([  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}}, {$addfields: {duration:{$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}}} ])
 some error :"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addfields'",

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. You have to use mongo server version 3.4 or you can add all the other fields to the project stage in lower version.

Comment: @veeram sir iam using mongo db version v3.4.9

Comment: @Veeram  db.lights.aggregate([  {"$match":{"STATUS":"LIGHTS ON"}}, {$addfields: {duration:{$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}}} ])  sir i write any mistake please see this sir

Comment: Oh I see. Use   `$addFields` uppercase F